# Aptana function returns an object and AutoComplete

Tags: autocomplete, aptana, phpdoc

I'm using the [PHPDoc tag](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html) for the autocomplete function in Aptana Studio 3, but I have a problem when I use function return input class as an object like in the photo:

[image: Aptana Studio 3 function return input class]

What is the solution?